# How do I specify the value I am trying to SELECT is time only?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select only an time value in the standard 24hr format.
I have attempted the below and is not working for me (Syntax error).

```
SELECT to_char('08:45','HH:Mi') AS TIME FROM DUAL;
SELECT to_date('08:45','HH:Mi') AS TIME FROM DUAL;
```

---

Desired RESULT:

```
|TIME|
|08:45|
```

Comment: What is wrong with `select '08:45' as time`?  Oracle doesn't have a time data type.

Comment: for example if I later wish to add an 15 minute delay i.e. 08:45 + 00:15 would it go to 09:00 or 08:60?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Gordon said, there's no `TIME` data type in Oracle. Closest alternative to that would be an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`

Use `TO_DSINTERVAL` to convert your time string to an interval.

```
SELECT SYSDATE,
          TO_DSINTERVAL('00 ' || '08:45' || ':00') AS time,
SYSDATE + TO_DSINTERVAL('00 ' || '08:45' || ':00') AS date_plus_time
FROM dual;

SYSDATE             TIME                DATE_PLUS_TIME     
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
2018-10-26 18:12:58 +00 08:45:00.000000 2018-10-27 02:57:58
```